# Orientation Change - Background

Tags: android, orientation, landscape

If the phone is in landscape mode my app recognizes this with the accelerometer
(I use the accelerometer, because i do have 3 differnt orientations and other values for the change).
I change the orientation with the following code:

```
myLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable....);                 setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

When the orientation gets changed I see a distorted image for a few seconds. The reason of this is apparently that the BackgroundRessource gets changed before the change of orientation.

I have tried to use layout-land and layout-port folders with the consequence that i have in the landscape orientation always a distorted image.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem except that i just get a black screen when switching to landscape. Saw someone mention creating a new drawable-land folder which might work for you...didnt work for me tho.

Just got this answer myself from a member here. Give it a shot.

```
@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.main);

 LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
 Resources res = getResources();
 Drawable portrait = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.portrait);
 Drawable landscape = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.landscape);

 WindowManager window = (WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
 Display display = window.getDefaultDisplay();
 int num = display.getRotation();
 if (num == 0){
     linearLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(portrait);
 }else if (num == 1 || num == 3){
     linearLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(landscape);
 }else{
    linearLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(portrait);
 }
}
```